# jquery replace new line with </br>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. When I change after focusing out **new line** on **br** tag, the first time is ok. However, next focus out add more tags br. Here is my code:

```
 $('.myDiv').on('focusout', '* > textarea', function(e)
    {
        $target         = $(e.target);
        //replace all enters to br tag
       $target.parent().append($target.val().replace(/\n/g, ' </br>'));    
    })
```

Comment: You can't put HTML in a textarea.

Comment: It's a TEXTarea, not an HTMLarea.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan He's not putting it in the textarea. He's appending to the parent of the textarea.

Comment: @Barmar Oops, Didn't notice :)

Comment: Each time you focus out you're appending, but you're never removing the previous one. So it will just keep repeating them.

Comment: But I'm not sure what that has to do with `<br>` tags. It should replace them the same way each time.

Comment: Can you create a  [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and include the HTML that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. I'm not entirely sure what your problem was, but it isn't happening now. This works:

```js
$("#parent").on('focusout', 'textarea', function(e){
  let $target = $(e.target), $value = $target.val();
  let regEx = new RegExp('\n', 'g');
  $target.next(".content").html($value.replace(regEx, "<br>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <textarea>Type in me!</textarea>
  <div class="content">
  
  </div>
</div>
```